# DialogFragment DatePickerDialog does not return changed date

Tags: android, datepicker, android-dialogfragment

I have datepicker dialogframgent within a fragment and when I log the dates in the *onDateSet()* method I only get the original date not the changed date from the datepicker spinner. I have been following the example from http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/pickers.html because I'm new to android. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Dialog Fragment

```
public static class DobFragment extends DialogFragment implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener{

        final Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        DatePicker picker;

        protected DialogInterface.OnClickListener btn_ok_listener = new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                picker.clearFocus();
                onDateSet(picker, picker.getYear(), picker.getMonth(), picker.getDayOfMonth());
            }
        };

        @Override
        public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
            View spinner = inflater.inflate(R.layout.date_spinner, null);

            int year = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            int month = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            int day = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

            DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day);
            picker = datePickerDialog.getDatePicker();

            datePickerDialog.setCancelable(true);
            datePickerDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
            datePickerDialog.setView(spinner);
            datePickerDialog.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE, "Ok", btn_ok_listener);
            datePickerDialog.onDateChanged(picker,picker.getYear(),picker.getMonth(),picker.getDayOfMonth());


            datePickerDialog.setTitle("Birthday");

            return datePickerDialog;
        }

        @Override
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {

            Log.v("dates",String.valueOf(picker.getYear()) +"-" + String.valueOf(year) +"-" + String.valueOf(calendar.getTime()));
//            Intent intent = new Intent();
//            intent.putExtra("result",formattedDate);
//            getTargetFragment().onActivityResult(getTargetRequestCode(), 1, intent);
        }
    }
```

Show Dialog Method

```
public void showDobDialog() {
    FragmentManager fragManager = myContext.getFragmentManager();
    DialogFragment frag = new DobFragment();
    frag.setTargetFragment(this,1);
    frag.show(fragManager, "dob");
}
```

Date Spinner Layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<DatePicker
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:datePickerMode="spinner"
    android:calendarViewShown="false">
</DatePicker>
```

Log From OnDateSet

```
2015-2015-Fri Aug 07 19:35:55 PDT 2015
```

My DatePicker Test Run - Original Date Aug 07, 2015

[image]

Comment: When I don't set my own view it works properly, but I want a spinner instead of a calendar.

Answer (score 0):

try this

@Override public Dialog onCreateDialog(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

```
    final AtomicBoolean buttonPressed = new AtomicBoolean();
    final DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), null, yearOfBirth, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth) {
        @Override protected void onStop() {
            super.onStop();
            if (!buttonPressed.get()) {
                callback.dialogDismissed(DobFragment.this, false);
            }
        }
    };

    datePickerDialog.setTitle(dialogTitle);
    OnClickListener listener = new OnClickListener() {
        @Override public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            buttonPressed.set(true);
            boolean okSelected = which == BUTTON_POSITIVE;
            callback.dialogDismissed(DobFragment.this, okSelected);
            if (okSelected) {
                DatePicker datePicker = datePickerDialog.getDatePicker();
                //DatePicker does not take the value in the picker as final value entered by the user, instead it take the index of the current value
                //The below line clear the focus on the date picker making it update all its indexes and delivering the right values when clicking Set
                //button.
                datePicker.clearFocus();
                callback.onDateSet(datePicker, datePicker.getYear(), datePicker.getMonth(), datePicker.getDayOfMonth());
            }
        }
    };
    datePickerDialog.setButton(BUTTON_NEGATIVE, "Cancel", listener);
    datePickerDialog.setButton(BUTTON_POSITIVE, "Set", listener);
    return datePickerDialog;
}
```

Comment: Do you have any idea why I get the proper changed date when I don't set datePickerDialog.setview(spinner) ? But not when I use my custom view?

Comment: can you give more detail about your custom view.

Comment: Its just the date_spinner.xml file from above. I inflate it and then set it as the view with datePickerDialog.setView(spinner). I do that because if I don't I'm stuck with the calendar date picker, and I want it as a spinner for convenience and              picker.setCalendarViewShown(false);
picker.setSpinnersShown(true); have no effect.

Comment: Can you elaborate why you need spinner and what type. As the code which i shared is also give you a date dialog in which you can just scroll up and down for date change.